# Modifying server's response to API endpoint

Tags: plugins, php, rest-api, headers, errors

I have a Javascript application in the front-end, with Wordpress in the back.

The `index.php` of Wordpress serves the application if user is logged in, else redirects to login page.

My application attempts to make form submissions via AJAX to Wordpress database.

Currently, I am using Formidable Forms API to submit an entry into a form, but the response I am getting is

```
code: "jwt_auth_bad_auth_header"
data: { status: 403 }
message: "Authorization header malformed"
```

My request in JavaScript is as follows:

```
let submission = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(APIKEY+':x')}`
    },
    body: payload
})
```

The problem is, I know this header should work because I have another application running (similar set up). And I have triple checked the API key itself.

At this point, I am trying to modify the server's response to send back the header, so I can determine what exactly it thinks I am sending.

Alternatively, trying to view any logs Formidable or Wordpress might keep.

How would I go about doing this?

In `FrmAPIAppController.php`, there seems to be a promising static method `process_response`:

```
private static function process_response( $response ) {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        $processed = array( 'message' => '', 'code' => 'FAIL' );
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            $processed['message'] = $response->get_error_message();
        } elseif ( $body == 'error' || is_wp_error( $body ) ) {
            $processed['message'] = __( 'You had an HTTP connection error', 'formidable-api' );
        } elseif ( isset( $response['response'] ) && isset( $response['response']['code'] ) ) {
            $processed['code'] = $response['response']['code'];
            $processed['message'] = $response['body'];
        }

        return $processed;
    }
```

It would be great if I could just `console.log` some variables, but I lack knowledge/experience in PHP/Wordpress/backends in general.

Thanks.

Comment: In my dashboard, the Formidable API is activated. Also, going to mywebsite/wp-json returns a long list of endpoints including the CRUD routes for forms & entries etc.

Comment: This seems very specific to the plugin, have you considered asking their support? [There is an article about debugging WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), most important for you would be to set `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and then use `error_log()` (where you would use `console.log()` in JS)

Comment: @kero Thanks for your suggestions kero. I have submitted a ticket, and check out the article.

Comment: The error message implies that the API is expecting a JSON Web Token for authentication, and I haven't used JWT myself, but your JS appears to be sending a Basic Authentication header, not `Bearer <token>`, which appears to be the norm for JWT. What happens if you change the Authorization header to `'Bearer ' + APIKEY`?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Hi. I've tried a few things (the results make the situation even stranger).

Bearer and API key returns a 403 result `Wrong number of segments`.

However, when using `Bearer` + the JWT received from `simple-jwt-authentication` plug in seems to return yet another 403 result `Sorry, you are not allowed to create entries`

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue now. There is a conflict between Formidable API and JWT Authentication for Wordpress Rest API plugin, none of which offer ways to deactivate authentication on specific routes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/257749)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).